# Trying to speed up doing a regex_search function with X strings on Y files

Tags: c++, performance, beginner

The point of this project is to be able to create an excel configuration file where the user can input search strings and search files, both potentially having wildcards, and search those files for those strings.

The problem is that while I have working code, it just simply takes the program too long to run. Based on what I've seen from people reading in files on google through C++, my program is incredibly slow even though I use getline and have seen much faster results from people using getline on stackexchange, for example. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```c
int main()
{
    // Here you enter in the file path to an excel file that has two columns: Search Strings, 
    // and Search Files. 
    // Search Strings are strings that can contain wildcards or escaped special characters
    // but not commas because that screws up the file reading too much. (Wildcard can be used
    // in place of comma and will return line text w/comma there.

    cout << "Please enter in the excel config. path " << "\n";
    cout << "Note this must be valid for the program to work correctly. LIMIT 100 CHARS " << "\n";
    string excelPath;
    char input[100];
    cin.getline(input,sizeof(input));
    excelPath = input;

    // User can input the file path to an excel csv where output results 
    // will be written.
    cout << "Please enter in the file path where you would like an output .csv file written: LIMIT 100 CHARS " << "\n";
    string outputExcel;
    char oInput[100];
    cin.getline(oInput, sizeof(oInput));
    outputExcel = oInput;

    // Get Search Strings + Search Files with this side function.
    bool openedFile;
    openedFile = useExcelConfig(excelPath);
    size_t found;

    // Main body of function is here.
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    if (openedFile == true)
    {
    // Defining required variables here.
        smatch matches;
        vector<regex> expressions;
        for (int i = 0; i < regex_patterns.size(); i++) { expressions.emplace_back(regex_patterns.at(i)); }

        for (size_t j = 0; j < searchFiles.size();j++)
        {
           // Defining some more variables here (that are mainly used in writing the csv data, not in the main file reading code)       
            vector<int> lineNumber;
            vector<string> lineText;
            string fileName;
            string folderName;
            fileName = searchFiles.at(j);
            int fileNameSlashIdx = fileName.rfind("\\");
            folderName = fileName.substr(0, fileNameSlashIdx);
            fileName = fileName.substr(fileNameSlashIdx + 1, string::npos);
            vector<string>lineStrings;
            string entireFile;

            // File ifstream definition/opening
            ifstream file;
            file.open(searchFiles.at(j), ios::in | ios::ate);

            // Fill and close file
            if (file)
            {
                ifstream::streampos filesize = file.tellg();
                entireFile.reserve(filesize);
                file.seekg(0);
                while (!file.eof())
                {
                    entireFile += file.get();
                }
            }
            file.close();

            /*
            auto regexstart = high_resolution_clock::now();
            for (size_t r = 0; r < expressions.size(); r++)
            {
                ptrdiff_t number_of_matches = distance(sregex_iterator(entireFile.begin(), entireFile.end(), expressions.at(r)), sregex_iterator());
            }
            auto regexstop = high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(regexstop - regexstart);
            cout << "Time spent on testing this new method: " << duration.count() << "\n"; */ 

            int linecount = 0;

            auto regexstart = high_resolution_clock::now();
            stringstream stream(entireFile);
            while (1)
            {
                string line;
                getline(stream, line);
                if (!stream.good())
                    break;
                for (size_t r = 0; r < expressions.size(); r++)
                {
                    //cout << "Current line: " << line << "\n";
                    //cout << "Current REGEXP: " << regex_patterns.at(r) << "\n";
                    //ptrdiff_t number_of_matches = distance(sregex_iterator(line.begin(),line.end(), expressions.at(r)),sregex_iterator());
                    //cout << number_of_matches << "\n";
                    found = regex_search(line, matches, expressions.at(r));
                    if (found == 1)
                    {
                        lineNumber.push_back(linecount);
                        lineText.push_back(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Running this section of code on a file of size 1875 KB takes 17 seconds. Using tests to figure out where the time is spent:
            // All the time is spent not on the regex search of the line but on the actual file reading.
            // How can I speed this up? 
            auto regexstop = high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(regexstop - regexstart);

            entireFile.clear();
            ofstream myOutPut(outputExcel);
            myOutPut << "Line Text, Line Number, File Name, Folder Path," << "\n";
            {
                tuple<vector<string>, vector<int>, string, string>result = make_tuple(lineText, lineNumber, fileName, folderName);
                writeResultsToFile(result, outputExcel);
            }
            lineText.clear();
            lineNumber.clear();
            cout << "Finished file " << (j + 1) << " of " << searchFiles.size() << "." << "\n";
        }
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "Elapsed Time: " << duration.count() << " seconds." << "\n";
    cout << "Full time during file search is: " << duration.count() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I included some code here that isn't where most of the time is taken so that you can get a good idea of what is going on. The main file reading loop takes forever and I've tried multiple different ways that I've seen people on google try.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please add example input so that reviewers are able to test run your code.

Comment: Also, please add the definitions for `regex_patterns`, `searchFiles`, and at least the declarations for `useExcelConfig` and `writeResultsToFile`.